# React hook form pass data to react input component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm new to React and TypeScript and I'm trying to create a simple form I had this working until I tried to create an Input Component. Now I'm struggling to pass through the data.

My Form.tsx looks like this

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import Input from '../UI/Inputs/Input';

interface FormData {
    website_url: string;
}

const Form = () => {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<FormData>();

    const onSubmitHandler = (data: FormData) => {
        console.log(data);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <form className='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
                <Input label='What is your website URL?' className='input' name='website_url' type='text' register={register} required />

                <button className='btn btn--primary' type='submit'>
                    Send
                </button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

And my Input.tsx like this

```
import { UseFormRegister, FieldValues } from 'react-hook-form';

interface Props {
    label: string;
    className: string;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    required: boolean;
    register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>;
}

const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({ label, className, name, type, required, register }) => {
    return (
        <fieldset className='form-fieldset'>
            <label htmlFor={name} className='label'>
                {label}
                <input type={type} className={className} id={name} register={register} required={required} />
            </label>
        </fieldset>
    );
};

export default Input;
```

The error I get in VS Code is `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': label, class, name, type, and 3 more.`
And this compile error

````
Type '{ type: string; className: string; id: string; register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>; required: any; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'register' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>```
````

Comment: you are calling a callback in the `regietr` attribute of the input html tag. First i'm not aware of such attribute name. Second you are not passing the callback itself but the result of the function because you are calling it on each render. To me it's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: the register function is being directly being called when your component is rendered, because your passing register(). Try passing only a refrence to the function : register={register} or register={() => register()}

<Input label='What is your website URL?' className='input' name='website_url' type='text' required={true} register={register} />

Comment: I've updated my code but still returns the same error.

Comment: I see on the [doc](https://react-hook-form.com/ts/#NestedValue) that the syntax for Typescript is `<input {...register("firstName")} placeholder="Bill" />`, so in your case `<input type={type} className={className} id={name} {...register(name)} required={required} />`

Comment: That's because the `register` property doesn't exist on the `input` component, what you need to do is invoke the `register` method, which returns a `UseFormRegisterReturn` object containing properties that do exist on `input`.
You can see the typing [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/5814379c738eb393a6701112ecb5222a48220dad/src/types/form.ts) or through VS Code by doing F12 on the register method.

Comment: You're also going to run into a problem doing it this way. One of the things `register` returns is a `ref`, which you can't just pass as any other prop. You'll have to use `React.forwardRef` to make this component work